# update trigger updating all rows in target, not just updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, geospatial

I have a very suspicious feeling that this update trigger is updating ALL rows on the target, not just those that satisfy the "update(shape)" test. Performance was fine 'till I added the second operation. A single spatial join occurs much faster, and this is a not a spatial index issue, as well, there are only a few records in this dataset.

```
ALTER TRIGGER   [dbo].[GRSM_WETLANDS_Point_GIS_tbl_locations_update]
ON  [dbo].[GRSM_WETLANDS_POINT]
after update  
AS   
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  if UPDATE (shape)
update GRSM_WETLANDS_Point
set X_Coord =CASE WHEN u.shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN u.shape.STCentroid().STX ELSE u.shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STX END,
    Y_Coord =CASE WHEN u.shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN u.shape.STCentroid().STY ELSE u.shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STY END
    from inserted i 
inner join GRSM_WETLANDS_POint u on i.GIS_Location_ID = u.GIS_Location_ID;
--second spatial operation
update GRSM_WETLANDS_Point
set QuadName = grsm.dbo.USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.name 

FROM GRSM_WETLANDS_POint i
inner join grsm.dbo.USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES  
on i.GIS_Location_ID = i.GIS_Location_ID  
WHERE  (USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.Shape.STContains(i.SHAPE) = 1) ;

end
```

Is my suspicion right?

Upated: Based on suggestion from Aaron...solves the fire on all rows issue.

```
update GRSM_WETLANDS_Point
set QuadName = grsm.dbo.USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.name 
FROM inserted i inner join GRSM_WETLANDS_POint u on i.GIS_Location_ID = u.GIS_Location_ID
left outer join  grsm.dbo.USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES  
on i.GIS_Location_ID = i.GIS_Location_ID  
WHERE  (USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES.Shape.STContains(i.SHAPE) = 1);
```

Comment: Where does your second operation indicate to only operate on rows affected by the trigger? I see no references to the `inserted` pseudo-table. Also your `if update` doesn't have a `begin/end` wrapper, so if you intended both operations to only occur for that condition, that isn't what will happen - the second operation will fire unconditionally.

Comment: If you want to update additional tables only if `value` of Shape changes, you need to join `inserted` to `deleted` table on primary key (assuming it does not change in update) and filter i.Shape <> d.Shape taking care of possible null values in either deleted or inserted copy of the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Shape` can't be NULL, a better way to see if it has changed is to check if the values in `inserted` and `deleted` are different. For example:

```
IF EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS i
  INNER JOIN deleted AS d
  ON i.GIS_Location_ID = d.GIS_Location_ID
  WHERE i.Shape.STEquals(d.Shape) = 0
)
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

If `Shape` is nullable then you just have to add more conditions there to check, e.g.

```
  WHERE 
  (
    (i.Shape IS NULL AND d.Shape IS NOT NULL
    OR (i.Shape IS NOT NULL AND d.Shape IS NULL)
    OR (i.Shape.STEquals(d.Shape) = 0)
  )
```

(You might not care if `Shape` has been updated *to* `NULL`, I'm just illustrating how to test for that case.)

Since the operation can occur on multiple rows, and this condition will only identify that at least one such update has occurred (but not that ALL rows meet the condition), it may be better to have your operations include similar criteria in the WHERE clause. In fact I think you can perform both updates in a single operation, e.g.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[GRSM_WETLANDS_Point_GIS_tbl_locations_update]
ON  [dbo].[GRSM_WETLANDS_POINT]
AFTER UPDATE
AS   
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  UPDATE p SET 
    X_Coord = CASE WHEN i.shape.STDimension() = 2 
      THEN i.shape.STCentroid().STX 
      ELSE i.shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STX 
    END,
    Y_Coord = CASE WHEN i.shape.STDimension() = 2 
      THEN i.shape.STCentroid().STY 
      ELSE i.shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STY 
    END, 
    QuadName = COALESCE(b.name, p.QuadName)
  FROM 
    dbo.GRSM_WETLANDS_Point AS p
  INNER JOIN 
    inserted AS i
    ON i.GIS_Location_ID = p.GIS_Location_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN grsm.dbo.USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES AS b
    ON b.Shape.STContains(i.Shape) = 1
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS i2
      INNER JOIN deleted AS d
      ON i2.GIS_Location_ID = d.GIS_Location_ID
      WHERE i2.GIS_Location_ID = i.GIS_Location_ID
      AND i2.Shape.STEquals(d.Shape) = 0
      -- ...and NULL handling if necessary
  );
END
GO
```

In general, you seem to be having a lot of troubles implementing triggers, and make a lot of guesses about how the syntax should work. Have you considered forcing data updates to occur via stored procedures, where you can control all of this business logic but eliminate the complexity that the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables add?

Answer (score 2):

if UPDATE (shape)  will fire even if the values don't change, if the column is present in the update statement it will fire

And you are not joining with INSERTED in your second update

Comment: Aaron, thanks for pointing out the obvious. I'm less clear, though, on how to isolate updates to the shape field, as both answers suggest.

Comment: @tpcolson I've added an answer to address this.

Comment: I would LOVE to get rid of all the overhead. Most of our business logic revolves around updates to GIS data, so....

Comment: I get `Msg 403, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GRSM_WETLANDS_Point_GIS_tbl_locations_update, Line 8
Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals not equal to, type equals geometry.` even when commneting out the X and Y coord answer code.

Comment: @tpcolson Sorry, not hip to the `geometry` stuff. But it was a simple fix, please try again.